# Does Linux Kernel Support RSA Encryption/Decryption?

Tags: cryptography, linux, rsa, api, kernel

I'm currently working on a prototype.  I need RSA Encryption at the Linux Kernel level,although from my research, it seems that the Linux Kernel only supports signature verification.  When I look through the code in rsa.c and rsa_helper.c, it seems that there is a rsa global struct that is set to static that has function pointers with variable names: encrypt and decrypt.

Also, there is not a lot of documentation on the asymmetric API.  The tcrypto.c does not even test any of the asymmetric crypto API.  This seems to be a huge limitation.  I am aware that asymmetric encryption is not as fast as symmetric encryption, but I need it for my prototype.

Hopefully,I will not need to roll my own RSA encryption/decryption routines, because this would be a major set back.

Comment: Have you checked the kconfig? It has options for enabling RSA in the Crypto API.

Comment: @forest Nvm, I see it.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/crypto/api-akcipher.html?

Comment: Yes, I did see that. It doesn't seem to give a lot of information, though.  For example, crypto_alloc_akcipher parameters are alg_name, type, and mask.  It doesn't really go into great detail of the values of those parameters to pass.  I guess I'll just have to do some digging in the source code.

Comment: If you just want to write a program that supports RSA, you don't need to call into the kernel to do that. It would be completely fine to use a library that implements RSA.

Comment: @forest The prototype I am building requires the rsa encryption to occur at Ring-0.  There are not libraries at that level.

Comment: For what possible reason would you _require_ encryption in ring 0? It's not more secure. Is your entire encryption program done in the kernel? You can do a lot more with the Crypto API from within a kernel module than from userspace. But if you're in user space, there's no need to do crypto in the kernel.

Comment: It doesn't need to be more secure.  I am writing kernel code, and encryption is necessary.  I'm sure the Linux developers didn't implement RSA at the kernel level for no reason.

Comment: Ok, if you're writing kernel code then this makes sense! I thought you were just using the userspace API via netlink. I do think `crypto/rsa.c` is what you want to look at, not akcipher.

Comment: @forest Yes, the prototype requires some kernel modification, which requires some encryption.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Linux Kernel supports RSA Encryption/Decryption.

Thanks to some comments I decided to dig a little bit deeper into the Kernel Source.  [This page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/crypto/api-akcipher.html) is sort of helpful.  It unfortunately doesn't require any code samples.

If you would like some code samples, then you can take a look at testmgr.c under the crypto directory.  It contains a comprehensive list of supported algorithms in the code.

Comment: Be careful. That implementation might not be resistance to side channel attack's

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does Linux Kernel support Elliptic Curve Cryptography? both encryption and decryption, not just signature verification.